# How to combine two lists of dictionaries of multiple entries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I have two lists of dictionaries and I want to combine or merge both of them. The obstruction here is I want to combine them based on the key value and this key value is different in every iteration, they are not fixed, how do I accomplish this?
Following are the two Lists of Dictionaries I have which needs to be merged.

```
l1 = [
    {'Fvcm':{
            'name' :'FVCM',
            'size' : 8,
             'Type' : 'Z'
            }
    },
    {'RPZM':{
            'name' :'RPZM',
            'size' : 8,
             'Type' : 'R'
            },
    },
    {'ZAN':{
            'name' :'ZAN',
            'size' : 8,
             'Type' : 'P'
            }
    }
    ]

l2 = [
    {'Fvcm':{
            'name' :'FVCM',
            'map' : 'Prim1'
            }
    },
    {'RPZM':{
            'name' :'RPZM',
            'map' : 'Prim2'
            },
    },
    {'ZAN':{
            'name' :'ZAN',
            'map' : 'Prim3'
            }
    }
    ]
```

and I want the final result to look like:

```
l3 = [
    {'Fvcm':{
            'name' :'FVCM',
            'map' : 'Prim1',
            'size' : 8,
             'Type' : 'Z'
            }
    },
    {'RPZM':{
            'name' :'RPZM',
            'map' : 'Prim2',
            'size' : 8,
             'Type' : 'R'
            },
    },
    {'ZAN':{
            'name' :'ZAN',
            'map' : 'Prim3',
            'size' : 8,
             'Type' : 'P'
            }
    }
    ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @music_junkie Currently what I do is I use nested for loops to iterate over items and when the key matches I combine them and add them to another list. I am checking if there is an optimized way other than the approach I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update), to merge 2 dictionaries together. That requires to modify your nested list-of-dicts structure into non nested dicts:

```
d1 = {k: v for item in l1 for k, v in item.items()} # regular k,v dict
d2 = {k: v for item in l2 for k, v in item.items()} # same
_ = [d1[k].update(v) for (k, v) in d2.items()]      # update each key in d1 with its corresponding value from d2
print(d1)
```

Out:

```
{'Fvcm': {'name': 'FVCM', 'size': 8, 'Type': 'Z', 'map': 'Prim1'}, 'RPZM': {'name': 'RPZM', 'size': 8, 'Type': 'R', 'map': 'Prim2'}, 'ZAN': {'name': 'ZAN', 'size': 8, 'Type': 'P', 'map': 'Prim3'}}
```

Comment: How dumb of me get confused with update! thanks :)